# MVC3 Partial Views and Google Analytics

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

What is the best way for tracking with Google Analytics and MVC3 Partial Views?

The best thing that I have found so far is to hook into the GET/POST for the partial views and put something like

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('/vpv/contact/')
```

Thoughts?

Comment: So you want to track partial views separately from your page views?

Answer (score 2):

I would just add the Google analytics JavaScript code at the bottom of my master page (layout view).  Doing it this way it can be used on all views that uses this master page with out having to duplicate your code on every view.

Add your Google Analytics code just before the closing body tag .  The reason is to improve page load performance.

Comment: What happends with partial views displayed via Ajax? I suppose the google analytics at the bottom of the masterpage.